# How do I programmatically login with IdentityServer4 using code

Tags: c#, identityserver4

So here's my code that I'm trying.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(_environmentConfiguration.AuthorityLoginRequestUrl);
string content = $@"Username={ userID }&Password={ userPassword }";
var request = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
_httpClient.SetBearerToken(token.AccessToken);
var response = await _httpClient.PostRequest(uri, request);
```

The response I get back is a status 400: Bad Request.

Obviously there is something wrong with the request. Either headers/cookies and/or query.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should enable logging on IdentityServer and see what's actually happening

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I have the source and yes logging is on. However, that is not helping me.

Comment: I think you are missing 'grant_type'. You can also use the code from the sample: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords/src/ResourceOwnerClient/Program.cs

Comment: Update of the link: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords/src/ResourceOwnerClient/Program.cs