# Get the UserID from the LoginResult class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, identityserver4

Please see the code below:

```
private async void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginResult _result= await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
}
```

I can get the claims of the user as follows:

```
var claim = _result.User.Claims
```

How can I get the user ID? Here is [a link to the LoginResult class](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2/blob/master/src/Results/LoginResult.cs).

Comment: @Anu Viswan, https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/blob/master/src/Shared/Results/LoginResult.cs

Comment: are you sure you are getting Claims as _result.User.Claims or is it _result.Claims ? LoginResult doesn't have a property called User.

Comment: @Amu Viswan, look here please: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2/blob/master/src/Results/LoginResult.cs.  The other link I posted is an old version.  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't UserId available in the `sub` claim?

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg, where? I have spent the last 3 hours looking.  Could you post some code?

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg, How do I get the sub from _result.User.Claims? If I iterate through _result.User.Claims then sub is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Xamarin, but I assume you can use linq:

```
// using System.Linq

var sub = _result.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value
```

This way you won't need to reference other packages. You can create your own extension based on this.

Comment: Is there a way I can establish whether or not the user is authenticated? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 You mean `_result.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?

Comment: Thanks.  That is it.  Finally do you know how I can authenticate a username and password programmatically rather than opening a web browser? You suggested a hyperlink in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800389/how-do-i-programmatically-login-with-identityserver4-using-code.  However, it no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

`LoginResult.User` is a [ClaimsPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8).  If you look at the docs for that class, it contains an `Identity` property which is the primary `IIdentity` associated with that `ClaimsPrincipal`.  `IIdentity` has a `Name` property, but not an `ID`.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you confirm it is not possible to get the user ID?